# How to detect network change events asynchronously in UWP apps

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10

I am building a UWP app where I am trying to detect different type of network event changes asynchronously.

Where user can make network changes and see the effect of their changes promptly.

For example -

- Airplane Mode ON/OFF detect asynchronously
- Bluetooth ON/OFF detect asynchronously
- Network connectivity ON/OFF detect asynchronously

I was able to detect Airplane Mode ON/OFF detect synchronously using following code

```
    public bool isConnectedToNetwork()
    {
        return NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile()?.NetworkAdapter != null;
    }

    private void checkAirplaneMode()
    {
        if(isConnectedToNetwork())
        {
            airplaneText.Text = "AirplaneMode: OFF";
        } 
        else
        {
            airplaneText.Text = "AirplaneMode: ON";
        }
    }
```

But I wanna (I would like to) do it asynchronously as network event changes.
So, User don't have to run the app again and again to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

UWP provides specific events to notify these changes, such as NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged Event ,BluetoothDevice.ConnectionStatusChanged Event.

If you want to detect network change events, you could [register for notifications of connection state change events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj835820(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#registering-for-notifications-of-connection-state-change-events).

```
// register for network status change notifications
networkStatusCallback = new NetworkStatusChangedEventHandler(OnNetworkStatusChange);
        if (!registeredNetworkStatusNotif)
        {
            NetworkInformation.NetworkStatusChanged += networkStatusCallback;
            registeredNetworkStatusNotif = true;
        }
```

Then you could [retrieve the connection state change information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj835820(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#retrieving-the-connection-state-change-information) and add your trigger code.

```
async void OnNetworkStatusChange(object sender)
{
// get the ConnectionProfile that is currently used to connect to the Internet                
        ConnectionProfile InternetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        if (InternetConnectionProfile == null)
        {
            //add code about not connected
        }
        else
        {
            //add code about connected
        }
}
```